# I'm looking for a drywall finish that will hold a magnet

Tags: drywall

I want to modify a wall so that small magnets will stick, and even hold a small dead weight. I would prefer that the magnetic area not look all that different from the rest of the wall, I don't want to just hang a sheet of steel. I am imagining that 1/4" mesh hardware cloth could be attached to the face of the drywall, and skimmed over with joint compound. We will be skim-coating the walls in any case to get a specific plaster texture.

The [hardware cloth I've looked at](http://www.homedepot.com/p/YARDGARD-4-ft-x-5-ft-Hardware-Cloth-308234B/202285863?N=bqpgZ1z0zbtl#.UjjfTcakrmN) has 1/4" openings, and is woven from 23 gauge steel and zinc galvanized. Magnets stick nicely to the bare cloth. My concern is that the joint compound will react badly with the galvanization causing the wall surface to check or fail in time.

The wall in question is in a full bath, and so humidity is likely to be higher than in the house in general. One of the proposed locations is directly behind the sink, the other is open wall. We are still discussing the right spot.

Is this a viable approach? If not, what else should I consider?

**Update:** My intent is to use rare-earth magnets to hold up a glass [mirror](http://amzn.com/B00CKMJMMI) behind a bathroom sink. The mirror is a 20 inch square cut into seven pieces forming [a puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangram). Using magnets to mount the mirror will allow guests to play with the shape of the overall mirror on the wall. My plan is to epoxy three [NdFeB magnets](http://amzn.com/B00CJJOIVM) to the back of each puzzle piece, or possibly just one on the smallest pieces.

The back of an envelope says that 400 square inches of 0.25 inch glass should weigh a couple of pounds, but I probably should go weigh the actual pieces since Amazon thinks the shipping weight is 4.6 pounds and there can't be all *that* much cardboard in the box.

Assuming the 4.6 pound figure is correct and that the box accounts for about .6 pound, the smallest pieces would 1/16 the total weight, or about 4 ounces, and the largest pieces would be 1/4 the weight or about a pound.

So the bottom line is that I do need a surface that will allow magnets to hold up about a pound.

**Final Update:** As all things in a home remodel are in continuous flux, this plan has fallen by the wayside. The answers and discussion have been helpful. I believe the mirror will find a home on a steel-backed whiteboard in the home office, and something more conventional will end up on the walls next to the sink.

I still plan to play with the magnetic primer paint, but from all I've read I'm not expecting it to work out to hold up anything more than a few sheets of paper. With that in mind, the answer pointing to the useful permanent magnet calculator gets the coveted green checkmark mostly because it has been the most useful in guiding us towards a location and use for the mirror.

Comment: stainless steel sheet with some wallpaper/paint would do fine

Comment: @ratchetfreak, I would prefer to match the paint and hand-worked plaster texture so that the region where magnets stick does not have obvious edges. Otherwise, I would just frame a sheet of steel and hang it like a picture... which still might be the best alternative.

Comment: @ratchetfreak some types of stainless are not magnetic.

Comment: @mac, for example the specific stainless steel alloy they made my refrigerator doors from. Given that they had a choice, I do wonder sometimes what fool decided to make a fridge door non-ferromagnetic?

Comment: FWIW, I would not hang glass objects using any technique that I wasn't *completely* confident in.

Comment: Don't do stainless steel. It may not be magnetic. Just prime and paint, or otherwise coat, a sheet of regular steel.

Comment: "Don't do stainless steel because it might not be magnetic?" Do you people think he's an idiot? He's not going to buy the steel, bring it home, mount it and plaster over it and then find out, d'oh, magnets don't stick to it! Of course you bring a magnet with you when you go shopping; don't buy any material for which you don't have first hand evidence that it is magnetic.

Comment: If this was in a public bathroom, and your insurance company knew about your plan, they'd likely want you to use plexiglass mirror panels rather than glass. Magnets or no magnets, this puzzle is somewhat of a safety hazard. It might not be horribly dangerous, but the element is there. I mean, people (possibly children?) are freely handling one pound glass panels. People have wet, soapy hands in bathrooms, too.

Comment: This is in my home, and I'm aware of the small risks associated with glass mirrors. I also tend to believe (foolishly?) that my guests are not complete fools....

Comment: Check my answer suggestion of vinyl coated steel for the best surface I have found in my research. Secondly, it may not be best suited for plastering, simply because vinyl is waterproof, but worth considering the option of a quality wallpaper and priming the vinyl surface or using an alternative non-water-based glue (may be better suited for a bathroom in either case).

Comment: (continued): 
 
The magnets you mention are nice rare earth magnets, but you can get more strength in smaller size for around the same price with samarium based magnets. Using just four 1/4"  rounds 1/16" thick, I can mount a steel 2' x 4' dry erase board @ 3 pounds sticking to only 4 drywall nails hidden unseen under the paint on the walls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to securely hold objects that heavy to the wall using magnets, I think you need to be working with sheet metal on top of the drywall (or in place of the drywall).

The magnetic force will [fall off very quickly with distance](http://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp#) away from the plate, so even skim-coating with plaster will dramatically reduce the holding power of the magnet.

[image]

If you want the surface to blend in with the surrounding walls (you didn't actually state the finish on the walls, but I'm assuming it's painted sheetrock or plaster), try simply painting the steel sheet to match. The texture of the finish might be slightly different, but I'd imagine it wouldn't take away from the feeling that it "blends in" with the surrounding walls.

As others have stated, I'd also consider a polycarbonate mirror rather than glass.

Comment: The wall finish is a plaster skim coat over drywall, in the "catfaced" style. The top coat is a skim coat applied with deliberate voids that are perhaps 1/32" deep and typically about a square inch of total area. I can paint a steel plate the same (or a deliberately contrasting) color, but I don't think I can readily match the texture. I'm not interested in machining a steel plate to have faux-plaster finish.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that calculator, I have other uses for that sort of information.

Answer (score 3):

They make a [magnetic primer](https://www.rustoleum.com/CBGProduct.asp?pid=127) that just paints on the wall under your paint.  I have not personally used it but in theory its by far the easiest option.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an interesting idea. I didn't know this material existed. Reviews at Walmart and Amazon are mixed, but that may indicate that many people don't follow directions then complain... I may have to acquire some and experiment to see if it will work for me.

Comment: I've used this. It does not work very well. If you have super strong magnets and lightweight objects, it is OK, but it's not anything remotely resembling the hold of a refrigerator (e.g.). The texture does vary a bit from regular paint (it's basically just metal powder mixed into the paint).

Comment: @Reid, see my update. One pound flat object glued to three strong magnets. Does that seem plausible in your experience?

Comment: If people are going to be sliding magnets over this all the time, I'd be worried about the paint coming off, even if the paint *wasn't* attracted to the magnets!

Comment: @RB, Sorry, it's been too long for me to say. But see comment on question.

Comment: One pound flat object glued to three magnets? I don't think that's going to stick to a thin coat of some paint with suspended ferromagnetic particles (or whatever this is). Maybe if you put on fifty coats or something!

Comment: I've used it. IMHO, it's crap. After 5 coats I still couldn't get a magnet of any heft to stick. I finally  just got some sheet metal and painted that.

Comment: I've got a can on order to try some experiments. Reviews I've found online seem to be highly polarized, either "wow" or "ouch" and hardly any "meh". The bad reviews include a large percentage of obvious failures to follow directions, hence the urge to try it myself before buttoning the wall up.

Comment: @RBerteig be forewarned that the magnetic paint goes on a bit thick--especially after a few coats. So if you opt out of sticking with it, note that you will now have a bit of a raised spot to deal with if you decide to paint over it.

Answer (score 2):

I've done my research on a similar project. In my case, I was wanting to make a wall that looked like a wall, but would accommodate my hobby of collecting "Magnetic Poetry" and refrigerator magnets. My solution was not cheap, but exactly what I was looking for. If you decide to revisit this at some point, try doing a search for "vinyl coated steel" sheets in suitable size. I had to settle for a 4 foot wide run around the top of the room, with conventional painted drywall around the base and decorative molding strip between the two.

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to cut a chunk out of the wall and hang a steel plate **behind** the drywall, then repair the drywall.

Repairing the drywall is not as daunting a task as it sounds like.  See [here](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20052318,00.html) for more information.

If the magnets you use are anywhere near as powerful as the ones in [this stud finder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IKK0OI), then three of them will *easily* be able to hold a few pounds.

Comment: Small magnets won't be strongly attracted to steel plate that is 3/8" away (or whatever is the typical drywall thickness).

Comment: We have the room stripped down to studs at the moment, so floating plaster on expanded lath or putting something on either face of the drywall before final finish is certainly an option. This week. Soon, the options will be narrower.

Comment: @Kaz: The drywall in my home has two layers; I've measured it to be 1" thick.  That magnetic stud finder is attracted to the outlet-box nails **behind** the drywall strongly enough that it easily holds itself up on its own.

Comment: @mike: My logic does hold, because OP and I are talking about exactly the same thing.  That magnetic studfinder is not an electronic studfinder which uses magnets; it is literally just a really powerful magnet.  When I hold it up to the wall, it's attracted to the nails behind the wall so powerfully that it can hold itself in place.

Comment: @Mike: ...I'm aware of all those facts, but they don't change the fact that my answer is still correct.